# Rendering two VBO objects with different shaders in a single FBO

Tags: opengl, glut, vbo, framebuffer, fbo

I am having trouble in finding a way to render a cube with a simple God Ray shader and another VBO object drawS().. This code gives me both objects have the same God Ray effect. My aim is to give the drawS() its own effect. Any idea?

void COpenGLRenderer::Render(float FrameTime)
{
    // bind FBO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
if(Blur)
{
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, FBO);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ColorBuffer, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,
        GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT,
        GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depth_rb);
//

// render scene -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(&ViewMatrix);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
/*glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(5.0, 3.0, 5.0);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glutSolidSphere(0.5, 20.0, 12.0);
glPopMatrix();*/
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glutSolidCube(5.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(&ViewMatrix);
glTranslatef(-30.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
drawS();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

// blur ColorBuffer texture -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ColorBuffer);

//glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//if(Blur)
//{
    glUseProgram(GodRays);


    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    //glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

}

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. The title says that you want to use two shaders. But the code only uses one. Did you try using a second shader? What problems did you have with it?

Comment: my goal actually is to run two shaders on the same framebuffer one shader is implemented on one VBO object and the other shader is running separately on other object.